# Making the first trip using Schengen visa with UK Visa expiring in less than 3 months

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, france, uk-residents

I have got my **Schengen Visa** from **French embassy** but I couldn't make my first trip yet.

*Now I have less than 3 months for my UK visa to expire.*

*Is it still ok to make my first trip to Schengen area ?*

I don't want to be turned back at the airport.

P.S

- Mine is Multi Entry Schengen Visa Type C
- My itinerary is to visit Germany first then Austria and Finally France.

Comment: The Schengen countries really shouldn't care if you have a valid visa for the UK.

Comment: Oh that's good to know. But if I could get any official reference , it'd be great !

Comment: If the validity of the Schengen Visa ended on the same date as your UK Visa, that *might* be a sign that the Schengen Visa was issued against the UK visa. But even then such a assumption would be pure speculation for which no official reference could be given. A Border guard *might* take that aspect into consideration if you arrived for a visit with all of your household goods.

Comment: ha ha :) , I'm not gonna take my household goods and my schengen visa expires before UK visa therefore it shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here're the possible countries, that are not part of Schengen countries, one could go with Schengen visa.

UK visa matters if you're returning back to UK after the trip.

https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. To get a Schengen visa when you are a resident of several countries you need a given amount of time left on your resident visa. OP clearly had that requirement. Your answer ignores that part.

Comment: @Siva - Thanks for your answer, But my worry is mostly what if I am turned back at Berlin Airport because , I am making my first trip to Schengen country when there is less than 3 months for my UK visa to expire. While applying for schengen visa , we have to show the itinerary which starts and ends before 3 months of UK visa expiry. then only schengen countries grant the schengen visa. Now I got my schengen visa with me but I couldn't make as planned initially and now I have less than 3 months for my UK visa to expire and I'm yet to make my first trip.